# Why does 'itsdangerous' module return the signed text?

Tags: python, encryption

I'm wondering if anyone tell me why the 'itsdangerous' module returns the signed text as a portion of the string. As in:

```
>>> import itsdangerous
>>> 
>>> secret = 'my-secret-key'
>>> token = itsdangerous.TimedSerializer(secret)
>>> token.dumps('my-user-id')
'"my-user-id".Cj51kA.yuoSx6eK0LuuphWK0TlOBil2PM0'
```

I supposed I could just do something like this to get the hash:

```
token.dumps('my-user-id').split('.', 1)[1]
```

... but I'm surprised that I would even need to do this in the first place. The fact that the documentation doesn't explicitly mention this behavior or simply offer a method to strip out the signed text makes me nervous enough to question whether I'm doing something insecure. Thanks in advance for shedding light on the following questions:

1) Is there a good reason why the library would do this? 
2) What is the safest way to ensure I don't return the encoded string in plain text along with the hash?

Comment: It is for signing, not hashing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of itsdangerous is not encrypting your data, it just a simple tool to detect tampered data.

> ... When you get the data back you can easily ensure that nobody
>   tampered with it. [<sup>1</sup>](http://pythonhosted.org/itsdangerous/)

Therefore, you should encrypt it yourself, before or after signing it by this module.

Comment: The thing I hadn't adequately considered was that the information I'm encrypting doesn't actually need to be secret -- I'm using 'itsdangerous' for token generation and just signing a user id, which isn't privileged information. The benefit of the signing is getting it back and knowing that *I* am the one who signed it -- seems simple but didn't sink in until asking this question!

Answer (score 2):

`itsdangerous` signs the text or any other data so it can be transmitted via unsafe channels and then checked on the other end or upon retrieval from a database where it was stored that it wasn't changed/tampered.

So it creates a signature, adds it to the signed data and then checks upon retrieval that it wasn't tampered with. **The other side needs the data and the signature.**